# Can't connect Zeromq library

Tags: c++

I can't start a program that uses #include <zmq.hpp>.
This is my code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t ctx;
    zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, zmq::socket_type::push);
    sock.bind("inproc://test");
    sock.send(zmq::str_buffer("Hello, world"), zmq::send_flags::dontwait);
}
```

This is mistakes:

```
semenzuravlev@MacBook-Air-Semen Desktop % clang++ main.cpp -L/usr/local/include/ -lzmq
main.cpp:6:34: error: no member named 'socket_type' in namespace 'zmq'; did you mean 'socket_t'?
    zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, zmq::socket_type::push);
                            ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 socket_t
/usr/local/include/zmq.hpp:2182:7: note: 'socket_t' declared here
class socket_t : public detail::socket_base
      ^
main.cpp:6:47: error: no member named 'push' in 'zmq::socket_t'
    zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, zmq::socket_type::push);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
main.cpp:8:53: error: no member named 'send_flags' in namespace 'zmq'
    sock.send(zmq::str_buffer("Hello, world"), zmq::send_flags::dontwait);
                                               ~~~~~^
main.cpp:8:20: error: no member named 'str_buffer' in namespace 'zmq'
    sock.send(zmq::str_buffer("Hello, world"), zmq::send_flags::dontwait);
              ~~~~~^
4 errors generated.`
```

Help me please. I've already broken my whole head.

I can't start a program that uses `#include <zmq.hpp>`

Comment: Please read through [ask]. Including irreverent tags makes it harder to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is you are using an older C++ compiler version.

`zmq::socket_type` is only available in C++11 and greater.

If your compiler is older you can still use the original types, e.g

`zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, ZMQ_PUSH);`